# can not access JSON object using dot notation

Tags: json, node.js, webstorm

node v0.10.18
webstorm 6.0.1

I am trying to get the temperature from weather underground. I get the object using their API and i'm trying to access the actual temperature using:

```
<pre>
<code>
    request(url+state+"/"+city+format, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var objBody = JSON.parse(body);
            return objBody.current_observation.temp_f;
        }
        else if (error) {
            console.log('error: ' + err);
        }

    });
</code>
</pre>
```

I am getting an error of "unresolved variable" for objBody.current_observation.temp_f

I also tried using body.current_observation.temp_f directly and get the same error. I also tried to stringify it and get the same error.

any ideas?

Comment: `console.log(objBody)` - make sure those members actually exist.

Comment: `console.log('error: ' + err` - where's `err` taken from?

Comment: printing error gives--> error: null
printing objBody gives --> [object Object]

Comment: You should be able to view `objBody` as a hierarchy (in Chrome anyway). Can you just put a breakpoint there and check the object?

Comment: the error comes from webstorm, once I type the path for the variable i'm looking for, it shows that error. the console does not show any errors it just returns null to the reader of the method

Comment: well, the actual json object is not known to WebStorm when performing static analysis - thus the errors. I can suggest using JSDoc annotations to provide WebStorm with some information about your object. For example, create  a fake variable that will hold this json data, and use this var as a value of @param annotation to let WS know what the actual type is.

Comment: thanks lena, that worked. Just having a sample object in the same file, although in a different function, made it work.